# Are there specific terms for trigonometric functions raised to a power?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

Related to my other question, asking for a [Book on higher-power trigonometric equation simplification techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614752/book-on-higher-power-trigonometric-equation-simplification-techniques), I am interested to learn if there are specific terms for trigonometric functions that have been raised to a power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps "trigonometric polynomial"?

Note that

$$\cos(x)^n=2^{-n}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n$$

which can be expanded by the binomial theorem.

Comment: Would love a (non-Wikipedia) reference to that! Particularly if it includes worked examples.

Comment: For the Euler-Moivre formula, i.e., $\cos(x)=Re(e^{ix})$? Any textbook that introduces complex numbers should have that. The term "trigonometric polynomial" goes back to before Gauss, I'd look into books discussing the Fourier series for it.

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you for this.